# vectorized way to iterate over rows where each element of row is a list and compare with another data frame

Tags: python, pandas, list, vectorization

I have a master dataframe called RuleSet, where for Column "A" each element is a list of objects and the corresponding Column "Explain" contains its broad description;

[image: RuleSet Dataframe]

I have another dataframe with column "Z" which is a list; this is the input

[image]

my objective is to find corresponding column "Explain" whose column A is a super-set of Column Z, i.e. all elements of column Z is in Column A.

This is the expected Output:

[image]

for now what i am doing is iterating each element of Z and matching in each element of Ruleset, this is a very slow and inefficient process. How could I vectorize this.
loading rule set here:

```
df_rule_set=pd.read_csv("ruleset.csv")
def check_in_ruleset(x):
    for i,j in df_rule_set.iterrows():
        list_cbx_mod = x
        check =  all(item in x for item in j['A'])
        if (check==True):
            A = (j[0])
            Explain=j[1]
    if check==True:
        ret=1
    else:
        ret=0
    return Explain
```

then doing apply, lambda

```
C['Explain']=C['Z'].apply(lambda x: check_in_ruleset(x))
```

Comment: It is not very clear what you want to do. Can you provide the expected output?

Comment: Also provide the data as text

Comment: as the list [80,40] is contained in the first cell of the Ruleset dataframe, so the column Explain's ">40" should come in the expected output.

Answer (score 1):

Try via `explode()`+`merge()`+`groupby()`:

```
out=(df2.explode('Z')
        .merge(df1.explode('A'),how='left',left_on='Z',right_on='A')
        .groupby('Explain')['Z'].agg(list).reset_index())
```

**Note:** Since you didn't provide data as text so it is not tested

Comment: this helps, i will add data in text format, although it doesn't exactly solve my problem

Comment: could you please look at this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68924578/how-to-vectorize-an-iterrows-over-a-different-dataframe-calculation